# Phalcon Model - Same table structure split by YYYYMM

Tags: phalcon

I have 2 tables (1-n relationship, "Keyword" has many "KeywordData") and they are split by YYYYMM. They are in the same database.

Example, Jan 2014 records are in keyword_201401 & keyword_data_201401. Feb 2014 records in keyword_201402 & keyword_data_201402

How do I define the table name in the models so that the values are write/read from the correct _YYYYMM tables?

```
keyword_201401 (keyword_id, keyword, date)
keyword_data_201401 (data_id, keyword_id, source)

keyword_201402 (keyword_id, keyword, date)
keyword_data_201402 (data_id, keyword_id, source)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for setSource().

You can specify a specific table in your model (Keywords.php) like:

```
$this->setSource('keyword_201402');
```

Not good enough though, right? If you wanted it to be dynamic, you could do something like:

```
// Keyword.php
function getAllKeywordsByDate($date) {
    // $date might be 201401 or 201402
    $this->setSource('keywords_' . $date);

    // find the keywords from the table based on the date
    $keywords = $this->find();

    // pass keywords to keyworddata to get related models
    $dataset = (new KeywordData)->mergeKeywordAndKeywordData($keywords, $date);

    // send the full dataset back
    return $dataset;
}

// KeywordData.php
function mergeKeywordAndKeywordData($keywords, $date) {
    // $data might be 201401 or 201402
    $this->setSource('keyword_data_' . $date);

    $dataset = array();

    // find the keyword data from the table based on the date
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $dataset[] = array(
                'keyword'      => $keyword,
                'keyword_data' => $this->findByKeywordId($keyword->keyword_id)
            );
    }

    return $dataset;
}
```

You'd ultimately end up with an array, but, this should be pretty close to what you need. It's not really any less efficient than a normal model because the nature of 1-n relationships is a new query for each unique id record.

So, finally, in your implementation, you'd end up doing:

```
$keywords = (new Keyword)->getAllKeywordsByDate('201401');
```

Which could be interated over by:

```
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    print_r($keyword['keyword']); // keyword model ($keyword['keyword']->keyword)
    print_r($keyword['keyword_data']); // same /\
}
```